# Future Warning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in python and I am getting an error about an empty series. Can anyone explain what this means and how I can fix it? I am new to python and would also need advice on where to place the new code to prevent the error.

Here is my code:

````
import pandas as pd 
import recordlinkage

al_usa = pd.read_csv('al_all_reference_usa.dta.csv', index_col='id')
al_sample = pd.read_csv('al_final.dta.csv', index_col='company_number', low_memory=False)


indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block(left_on = 'state' , right_on = 'state')
candidates = indexer.index(al_usa, al_sample)
print(len(candidates))

compare = recordlinkage.Compare()
compare.string('companyname', 
               'name', 
               threshold=0.90, 
               label='business')
compare.string('state',
               'state', 
               threshold=0.90, 
               label='state')
pd.Series(dtype='float64')
features = compare.compute(candidates, al_usa,
                        al_sample)```


Here is the error: 

FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.conc = pandas.Series(list(zip(s1, s2)))
````

Comment: it's just a warning not an error

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. And the solution is what you did, adding `dtype='float64'`. *Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.*

Comment: @Guy  Thank you, I did not receive an output and this what appeared and the code stopped running. Is there something else that indicates an issue.

Comment: @QuestionHaver99 how do I see my output?

Comment: @econ_grad12345 you don't print it anywhere...